# Read json from file.json.bz2 quickly

Tags: python, json, pandas, bz2

I'm trying to open a bz2 file and read the json file contained inside. My current implementation looks like

```py
with bz2.open(bz2_file_path, 'rb') as f:
    json_content = f.read()
json_df = pd.read_json(json_content.decode('utf-8'), lines = True)
```

I need to repeat this process many times, and the the with block is taking up the bulk of the time. Is there a way which I can speed this process up?

Answer (score 2):

The following variation of your code won't necessarily read all the code into memory at once. Passing `encoding` to [bz2.open()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/bz2.html#bz2.open) allows the decoding to be done on the fly, and [panads.read_json()](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_json.html) can accept a file-like object to read incrementally.

```
with bz2.open(bz2_file_path, 'rt', encoding='utf-8') as f:
  json_df = pd.read_json(f, lines=True)
```